# ServiceStack calling authentication from my service

Tags: c#, servicestack

I would like to help a user to login from my service, so instead of directly Posting to the link '/auth/basics' or '/auth/credentials', I do this from inside my code:

```
public class LoginService : Service {
    public LoginResponse Post(Login req) {
        var authService = ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.AppHostBase.Instance.Container.Resolve<AuthService>();
        authService.RequestContext = new HttpRequestContext(
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ToRequest(),
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ToResponse(), 
            null
        );
        authResponse = AuthService.Authenticate(
                           new Auth{ 
                               UserName = req.UserName, 
                               Password = req.Password,
                               RememberMe = true 
        });
        if(authResponse.UserName != null) {
            //sccessful
            //and does it automatically write session to cookies too? 
            //or do I need to write to session manually?
        }

    }
}
```

This is what I have figured out so far. Is this the correct approach? I would like to confirm with you.

Comment: Does your approach work?

Comment: @J.Steen, hmmm. strangely, i only figured out how to write this half hour ago, but it works with FF, Chrome, and first time with IE, then every second time authResponse = null in IE...dunno why.

Comment: I was going to say, if it works, it's correct. However, as you seem to be having further issues I suggest you edit your question to be about *that* instead, to make it more clear and more specific. =)